# HTML5 Video dimensions in Safari IOS

Tags: ios, html, ipad, video

I'm building a website for a client who's majority of content is video. I'm using the HTML5 video element to display the content but have problems when it comes to Safari on iOS.

Safari on iOS does not download the video metadata until the user initiates the download, so the width and height properties of the video are set to a default size of 300 x 150 px - leaving a big area of black on either side of the video stretching the width of my containing element.

I'm trying to make the website as responsive as possible and so this default size does not work for me. Is there anyway to combat this so that Safari on iOS respects the video size?

Comment: I think this answer is correlated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250583/safari-on-ipad-ios6-does-not-scale-html5-video-to-fill-100-of-page-width

Answer (score 6):

I used the following CSS that worked for me. Tested on iPad mini with iOS 7.1

```
video {
 min-height: 100%; 
 min-width: 100%; 
 height: auto !important;
 width: auto !important; 
}
```

Comment: This did the trick for me, neater solution than hardcoding values. For my use it was "width: 100% !important;" though.

Comment: Will not work on small screens like mobile. The height will default to iOS minimum height for video.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for iOS can be achieved with pure CSS. This works for `<video>` that occupies the width of the viewport, which is common in mobile.

1. Based on viewport units

> 1vw = 1% of viewport width

2. Get the width percentage computation based on aspect ratio

If your video is 16:9

> 9 divided by 16 = 0.5625 = 56.25% = 56.25vw

If your video is 4:3 and 21:9 that would be 0.75 and 0.4285 respectively.

3. Apply these CSS rules

```css
    video {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
        max-height: 56.25vw !important;
    }
```

```html
<video>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The misbehaving iOS would be forced by the max-height to not grow taller than the ratio based on the width.

Comment: @KirillTolkachev you are most welcome :) Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Via CSS, try giving it a width of 100% and a height of auto.

***EDIT***
In this case you need to use JavaScript to wait until the video has loaded the metadata and then read and set the width and height, for example:

```
var v = document.getElementById('myVideo');
v.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(e) {
   this.width = this.videoWidth;
   this.height = this.videoHeight;
}, false);
```

I haven't exactly tested this but it should lead you on the right track.

Comment: This does not work, like I say, the video metadata is not downloaded, so although the video 'space' will stretch 100% to fit the containing element width, the video itself shrinks to 300 x 150 px. You can overwrite the default iOS video size by specifying a definite height and width, but since the website aims to be responsive this is not an option.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still not the answer. The video metadata is not loaded until the user explicitly initiates the download, so until that point the JS will not fire and the video remains in the iOS default dimensions.

Comment: Then I suggest you decide on a common set of dimensions and use that, then changing it to fit the video in question once it loads. What you realls need is CSS3 object-fit which isn't very well supported but there is a polyfill: http://www.steveworkman.com/html5-2/javascript/2012/css3-object-fit-polyfill/

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right about choosing a set of dimensions. It seems the only real work-around for this case.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `width:100%`, `height:0`, `padding-bottom:56.25%` (for 16:9 video) to set the size of the container element

Then get the container `height/width` to set the `height/width` of video element:

```
var the_case_study_video_wrapper = $('#tw-case-study-hero-video-wrapper'),
    the_case_study_video = document.getElementById('tw-case-study-hero-video'),
    the_height = $(the_case_study_video_wrapper).css('padding-bottom'),
    the_width = $(the_case_study_video_wrapper).css('width');

$(the_case_study_video).css({
   'height': the_height,
   'width': the_width
});
```

And then maybe set the css again on orientation resize and/or browser resize...

Answer (score -3):

I just set a fix width and height in css rule for video tag and safari displays the video properly.