# Video element sizing differences (mobile vs desktop)

Tags: css, html, html5-video

It seems that video element sizing behavior is different between mobile to desktop:
 on http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/tests/video.html
on desktop chrome its width is about 35% of the browser. on ipad chrome is about 10%

any ideas why? where can i get the rules to this?

thanks much

Lior

Answer (score 0):

Apple documents this non-standard behavior in this document, which is worth reading because it covers some other things you're going to have to worry about with video on the iPad.

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1

> **Default Height and Width on iOS**
>
> Because the native dimensions of a video are not known until the movie metadata loads, a default height and width of 150 x 300 is allocated on devices running iOS if the height or width is not specified. Currently, the default height and width do not change when the movie loads, so you should specify the preferred height and width for the best user experience on iOS, especially on iPad, where the video plays in the allocated space.

Also, have a look at this related question:

[Safari on iPad (iOS6) does not scale HTML5 video to fill 100% of page width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250583/safari-on-ipad-ios6-does-not-scale-html5-video-to-fill-100-of-page-width)