# fluid width html5 video not working in iOS

Tags: css, html

I am using below css to make it occupy video fluid width

```
  video {
     width:auto important;
     max-height:40px;
     display:inline-block;
  }
```

This works fine in Desktop browser but not working in iOS. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uLca7cnz/7/

Comment: what about setting height instead max-height?

Comment: @dippas No, it does not work

Comment: you are missing `!` from `important`, should be `!important` therefore the `width` won't be set

Comment: @dippas Still not working. It behaves as same.

Comment: it does need to be on fixed height? if not.. just deleted max-height.. (I don't have iOS so I'm just assuming things.. can't really test it)

Comment: you should try changing the `display` from `inline-block` to `block`

Comment: @dippas Tried your suggestions but it did not work.

Comment: sorry can't help you better since I'm not on iOS..

Comment: @dippas It's ok :) But I really appreciate your help

Comment: Setting max-width:50px worked fine. But it's just convincing solution for now.

Comment: Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250583/safari-on-ipad-ios6-does-not-scale-html5-video-to-fill-100-of-page-width
The accepted answer has a pretty good explanation for what's going on